# C++ Object Serialization [Exception thrown at 0x00007FF790BFADED]

Tags: c++, exception, object-serialization

I am writing Custom Object Serializer in C++. I don't have any problems serializing the object. However, after deserilizing the object, I get an error when closing the program or cleaning it. I have no idea what causes the problem.

**Error 1:**

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF790BFADED in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001E4E61DBED0
```

**Error 2:**

`Exception thrown: read access violation. \_Pnext was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

```cpp
#ifndef OBJ_SER_API_H
#define OBJ_SER_API_H

#include <fstream>

class ObjectSerialization
{
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize the provided object to a binary file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">The path to the binary file where the object will be serialized.</param>
    /// <param name="objectToWrite">The object to be serialized.</param>
    template<typename T>
    static void Serialize(const wchar_t* filePath, const T& objectToWrite)
    {
        std::ofstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&objectToWrite), sizeof(objectToWrite));
        file.close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize an object from a binary file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">The path to the binary file from which the object will be deserialized.</param>
    /// <returns>The deserialized object.</returns>
    template<typename T>
    static T Deserialize(const wchar_t* filePath)
    {
        T object;
        std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&object), sizeof(object));
        file.close();
        return object;
    }
};

#endif // !OBJ_SER_API_H
```

Main:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ObjectSerialization.h"

class Student {
public:
    std::wstring Name;
    int Age = 0;
};

int main()
{
    // Serialization
    {
        Student student;
        student.Name = L"Michael";
        student.Age = 22;
        
        ObjectSerialization::Serialize<Student>(L"Student.dat", student);
    }

    // Deserialization
    {
        Student student = ObjectSerialization::Deserialize<Student>(L"Student.dat");
        std::wcout << student.Name << std::endl;
        std::cout << student.Age << std::endl;
    } // <- exception occurred


    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What causes this error and what should I do?

Platform: Win10

Even though I tried all C++ versions, I get the same error. I made the pointer version, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Why do you have these functions as static inside a class that is never instantiated, and not just within a namespace?

Comment: I'm kinda busy right now, can you do me a favor and run the debugger on your program?  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session, in plain text.

Comment: `std::wstring` is not trivially-copyable, so writing its bytes directly out to a file won't work.

Comment: Simply writing object data like this won't work with objects that contain pointers.

Comment: `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&object), sizeof(object));` you can't do that! No chance of working with a non POD type like wstring

Comment: @MilesBudnek I can read wstring data from the file. The problem occurs during the cleaning process.

Comment: @KorayÜstündağ It's undefined behavior. There is no guarantee how the program will behave. For non-trivially-copayble type you need to _actually_ serialize, not just write out object representation. It fundamentally can't work.

Comment: @KorayÜstündağ You can certainly read some bytes from your file and stuff them into a `std::wstring`'s storage, but that doesn't mean those bytes form a valid `std::wstring` object.

Comment: @KorayÜstündağ Here's what happens when you do that: The string object contains pointers to memory containing the actual string data. You serialize those pointers to disk, and then the object is destroyed. Later, when you deserialize it, you load back those pointers. They _might_ appear to work if the memory hasn't been overwritten yet, but that's just an unfortunate coincidence. When the object is destroyed, it attempts to free memory that it does not own and has not been allocated. Note that absolutely _nowhere_ did you write or read the actual characters of your string.

Comment: One edge case that may cause naive serialization code to appear working is Small String Optimization (often used as an acronym [SSO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/acronyms)). In short, for short strings, compiler might decide not to allocate the memory dynamically, but instead to store the data in-place inside the string object (reusing the space that a couple of pointers would occupy otherwise). This is not the case for longer strings (which don't fit into that limited space), so those will have pointers to real heap-allocated storage, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize that way, because your custom objects may contain pointers (like your string).

You may be lucky to read back your string, because you are deserializing *just after* the serialization and *on the same machine*.

Maybe the memory used before was not already allocated (and erased) by something else and thus the string data is still here.

However, the pointer to the string data was already deallocated during your serialization. (that does not mean the memory was erased).

And you are not reallocating it by the deserialization. The pointer **may** points to "valid" data, but then, when your deserialized object tries to deallocate it a second time, your OS complains that your program doesn't own this memory. (since you already deallocated it before)

To serialize in a proper way, you should create an interface to implement on your custom objects, and let your object classes handling their serialization.
Something like that:

```cpp
class Serializable {
    virtual void Serialize(std::ostream) = 0;
    virtual void Deserialize(std::istream) = 0;
};

class Student : public Serializable {
    virtual void Serialize(std::ostream) override {...}
    virtual void Deserialize(std::istream) override {...}
};
}
```

And then call those functions in your serializer class.

You can overload your template serializer functions to handle common types like `int`, `float`, `std::string`, etc.
And use these funtions as a basis to serialize more complex classes like your `Student` object.

I've made something like that for a network library some years ago (sorry if the code is not really clean), you can check the [`Serializer`](https://github.com/BenPyton/libnetwork/blob/master/includes%2FNetwork%2FSerializer.h) class on my github repo to see a possible implementation.